# What is the equivalent to old wives tales in Japanese

Tags: translation, expressions

What is the equivalent expression to "old wives tales"?

Comment: I think you need to add some background; an example sentence you want to use the expression in. Otherwise it's a plain translation request and the phrase is listed in common dictionaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common translation seems to be:

> [くだらない迷信](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%8F%E3%81%A0%E3%82%89%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E8%BF%B7%E4%BF%A1)
>
> 1. absurd superstition (英和対訳)
> 2. old wives' tale (英和対訳)
> 3. 迷信 (和英辞典)

Answer (score 1):

To make sure, you are referring to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_wives%27_tale), right?

There is an expression which looks similar (おばあちゃんの知恵; lit. "wisdom of old women"), but this has a *positive* connotation in Japanese.

The kind of "theories" listed in the Wikipedia article is plainly referred to as:

- 古【ふる】い迷信【めいしん】 (lit. "old superstition")
- 俗説【ぞくせつ】 (lit. "layman's theory", usually implies scientifically false ones)